# Adding parenthesis around SELECT expression gives an exception in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

The query below gives an error unless I remove the outer parenthesis starting after "AS", on the second line.

```
CREATE VIEW chinook.customer_gt_90_dollars AS
(
    SELECT c.* 
    FROM chinook.customer c LEFT JOIN chinook.invoice i ON c.customer_id = i.customer_id
    GROUP BY c.customer_id
    HAVING SUM(i.total) > 90
);
SELECT * FROM customer_gt_90_dollars;
```

It was my impression that parenthesis and whitespace can be added arbitrarily (as long as the resulting code still makes sense). I tried removing only the whitespace (the newlines), and it still doesn't run, so it seems that the parenthesis are the issue. What rules are there in SQL about where parenthesis are allowed? I could not find any existing questions answering this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQLlite, enclosing a SELECT  statement with parenthesis implies that it is a subquery and  "**The value of a subquery expression is the first row of the result from the enclosed SELECT statement**".
See documentation below ([link](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html))

> A SELECT statement enclosed in parentheses is a subquery. All types of SELECT statement, including aggregate and compound SELECT queries (queries with keywords like UNION or EXCEPT) are allowed as scalar subqueries. The value of a subquery expression is the first row of the result from the enclosed SELECT statement. The value of a subquery expression is NULL if the enclosed SELECT statement returns no rows.

This will cause your view definition to just have a result row after AS without any actual table definition.